# Should I upgrade my Windows 7 Professional 64bit to Ultimate 64bit, in place, or reformat method?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, installation

I'm feeling a little on the lazy side today, wondering what the tradeoffs are to doing in place upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft suggest a fresh install.  They Made it, I would listen to them.

Comment: Although this is correct I don't always do what Microsoft tells me to do...

Answer (score 4):

My response is: don't be lazy, because it will only nip you in the butt later on. A fresh install forces the computer to refresh drivers, temp files, and all the other crap that windows dumps on the PC. A fresh install usually only takes a few hours anymore anyways, which isn't much more than a typical upgrade.